# data analysis tools to integrate with node red and robo mongo

Tags: mongodb, node-red

node red is a gui tool,  using which we can wire hardware devices, APIs online,services together. I have a node red instance running,  which is an mqtt client that accepts messages from broker which are published from various sensors. All the data is being stored in monogodb. Now, i want to implement some kind of analysis on the data that is being sent from all the sensors. is there any data anlaysis tools that can be integrated with node red and anlayse the data that is being stored in monodb database.

Answer (score 0):

For the data analysis I would suggest "MongoDB with R".

https://datascienceplus.com/using-mongodb-with-r/

You also speak about integration with node-red but is it not sufficiently that the data analysis tool is integrated with the MongoDB (which is populated by node-red) ?  If not then you should clarify what kind of integration you need with node-red.

Answer (score 0):

So in assumption you can acces the DB from node-RED:

Its how far you want to analyze the data:

1. You can simply do it with function nodes and calculate means, standard deviation etc.
2. There is a node called [node-red-contrib-statistics](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-statistics) wich has many standard statistic test, like t-test, implemented.
3. You can just write a your analysis in a third party language, like python or R, and call it with the exec or node-red-daemon node